# What's a good tool for calculating web KSLOC?

Tags: javascript, html, css, size

For HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files, what's a good tool to run on source directories and get KSLOC?

Comment: I hope this is for curiosity's sake and not any sort of meaningful metric...

Comment: it's for management's sake and i wish you were my manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wc -l` is a good start.

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted. It does the trick and gives a meaningful number that's pretty much just as useful as any other SLOC metric.

Comment: fair enough. i was interested in an automated, configurable tool with reporting and code visualization options. but unless mgmt presses for more, a raw count will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -v -P "^\s*$" -R dir/ | wc -l
```

Gives you a line count that ignores blank lines.

Comment: thx. i'm on a solaris box, and a couple of those grep args aren't supported in this environment. ended up w/ something like: 
find dir/ | xargs grep -v "^$" | wc -l